# Zen Theme Outputting Term Desc in Node - How To Add To Views

Tags: views, 6

Hello i am using a zen based them [Plain Grail](http://drupal.org/project/plaingrail). I nitice that on nodes it shows the term description on hover in nodes. I would like to achieve this effect in some of my views.

I have seen this question asked on here before but because my theme is already outputting this i thought it best to ask a new question.

I cannot see any reference to this in Plain Grail or Zens template.tpl

Does anyone know how i can show the term description in Views? thanks

Drupal 6 and Views 3

Answer (score 0):

See source of term:

```
<a href="/index.php?q=taxonomy/term/1" rel="tag" title="Some descr term01">term01</a>
```

So term's descrtiption here just title attribute.
So for **Views** you can add field with link (or rewrite output), and put in Title some placeholder name.